# how can I use rollapply to access t-statistics and p values?

Tags: r

Please help and sorry for naive question. 
I have:

```
> head (g)
  bo_m          dax             bo_m_lag
1 -0.040131270  0.001842860      0.032612438
2  0.112425025 -0.018043681     -0.040131270
3 -0.078987920 -0.009463752      0.112425025
4 -0.011990692  0.020144077     -0.078987920
5 -0.005279136  0.013360796     -0.011990692
6  0.055994660 -0.004568196     -0.005279136
```

I need to run rolling-window regression with window=51. So I did:

```
> library ("zoo")
> dolm <- function(x) coefficients (lm(bo_m ~ ., data = as.data.frame(x), model=TRUE))
> res <- rollapplyr (g, 51, dolm, by.column = FALSE)

> head(res)
      Intercept       dax        bo_m_lag
[1,] 0.01695970 0.1548448       -0.3846233
[2,] 0.01752946 0.1381642       -0.3781836
[3,] 0.01300192 0.3028419       -0.3549629
[4,] 0.01415457 0.2012890       -0.3341618
[5,] 0.01601414 0.2639384       -0.3486120
[6,] 0.01684621 0.2733759       -0.3482895

> summary (res)
   Intercept              dax           bo_m_lag  
 Min.   :-0.030258   Min.   :-0.71994   Min.   :-0.64239  
 1st Qu.:-0.001953   1st Qu.:-0.05464   1st Qu.:-0.40524  
 Median : 0.003330   Median : 0.26794   Median :-0.35061  
 Mean   : 0.004174   Mean   : 0.35349   Mean   :-0.32037  
 3rd Qu.: 0.014527   3rd Qu.: 0.90471   3rd Qu.:-0.26593  
 Max.   : 0.030142   Max.   : 1.30679   Max.   : 0.01971
```

The questions: how can I calculate rolling-window regression to have t and p values?

thank you very much,
roman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `g` and run a revised `dolm` on it:

```
Lines <- "  bo_m          dax             bo_m_lag
 -0.040131270  0.001842860      0.032612438
  0.112425025 -0.018043681     -0.040131270
 -0.078987920 -0.009463752      0.112425025
 -0.011990692  0.020144077     -0.078987920
 -0.005279136  0.013360796     -0.011990692
  0.055994660 -0.004568196     -0.005279136
"

library(zoo)
g <- read.table(text = Lines,  header = TRUE)
dolm <- function(x) {
  co <- coef(summary(lm(bo_m ~., as.data.frame(x))))
  c(Est = co[, 1], SE = co[, 2], t = co[, 3], P = co[, 4])
}
r <- rollapplyr(g, 4, dolm, by.column = FALSE)
```

UPDATE: Corrections and simplification.

Comment: one more question: why it is not needed 'as.data.frame(x)' in function (x) and 'by.column = FALSE' in rollapply?

Comment: Good point. I have made the corrections and also noticed that the code to produce the names could be simplified upon moving it into the `dolm` function.

Comment: thank you very much. it works perfectly. But there is another problem here: I have 310 observations - the weekly data from 1986w15 till 2002w18; in a year there is appoximately 51-52 weeks. so I did window 52. With the step '1' the number of results result should be around 514. isn't it? but I got 258...

Comment: Not clear what step 1 refers to but if there are n rows in g and the window is w wide then there would be one row in r for each of these groups of rows in g: 1:w, 2:(w+1), ..., (n-w+1):n so that in total there should be n-w+1 rows in r.  For example, we have n=6 and w=4 above so n-w+1=6-4+1=3 and find that r does indeed have 3 rows.  For n=310, w=52 we should have 310-52+1=259 rows in r.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I have, for example, the following starts/ends (w=52): 
1996w17/1997w16
1996w18/1997w17
1996w19/1997w18
1996w19 1997w18
1996w20 1997w19
............... 
1999w1 1999w52
1999w2 2000w1 .............. 
2001w13/2002w12
2001w14/2002w13
2001w14/2002w13 and...it is 514...

Comment: Hi Guys if I apply this function to my dataset the correct amount of rows is created but in every row has the same values. Does someone know what happens by me?